# How to Slow Speed of Turtle - Python

Tags: python, python-turtle

This may seem an easy question to answer;
`t.speed(1)`. But, I want to know how to slow speed less than 1. 0 cannot work, because it is the fastest speed turtle can go. In my compiler (I'm not sure about yours), when I try to use 0.1, it rounds to 0 and goes fast. This is the part of my code you need to know:

```
import turtle
import random
... ...
artificial_players = [];
for i in range(2):
   _player = turtle.Turtle();
   _player.speed(1);
   _player.color('red');
   _player.shape('circle');
   ... ...
   artificial_players.append(_player);
for i in artificial_players:
         ... ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, we can't slow down an individual *turtle* any further with the given API, but we *can* slow down the *screen* as much as we desire using it's `delay()` method:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('slowest')

screen.delay(100)  # try code with and without this line

turtle.circle(175)

screen.exitonclick()
```

The argument to `delay()` is the number of milliseconds of delay to add to each update.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the `turtle.speed()` method converts all values that are not already accounted for into integers, so there is no way to process the speed directly by inputting floats, including integers below 1.

The speed can be set using a string, which is mapped to specific integer values.

```
    speeds = {'fastest':0, 'fast':10, 'normal':6, 'slow':3, 'slowest':1 }
```

If the speed value provided is `None`, then the `turtle` proceeds with the current speed.

```
    if speed is None:
        return self._speed
```

If the speed value given is in the dictionary of `speeds`, then that string mapping returns an integer value that is used.

```
    if speed in speeds:
        speed = speeds[speed]
```

If the value provided is a float between 0.5 and 10.5, then `turtle` just rounds it anyway.

```
    elif 0.5 < speed < 10.5:
        speed = int(round(speed))
```

For any other value, `turtle` automagically just considers the speed to be maxed out.

```
    else:
        speed = 0
```

### Reference(s):

[turtle.py source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/turtle.py)