# Is there a way to move turtle slower in Python Turtle Graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have made a program to move turtle position by pressing the keyboard, but is there a way to make it move in smaller increments of pixels?

and also, is it possible to move turtle up and down instead of only left and right?

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
TURTLE_SIZE = 200

# functions
def go_left():
    t.direction = 'left'

def go_right():
    t.direction = 'right'

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1152,648)
screen.tracer(0)

# player
t = Turtle()
t.shape("circle")
t.speed("slowest")
t.color("blue")
t.penup()
t.setx(338)
t.sety(0)
t.direction = 'stop'

# Keyboard
screen.onkeypress(go_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(go_right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

while True:
    x = t.xcor()

    if t.direction == 'left':
        if x > TURTLE_SIZE - 576:
            x -= 3
            t.setx(x)
        else:
            t.direction = 'stop'
    elif t.direction == 'right':
        if x < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
            x += 3
            t.setx(x)
        else:
            t.direction = 'stop'

    screen.update()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Slow Speed of Turtle - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65169497/how-to-slow-speed-of-turtle-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your dot was moving so fast was because of your `while True` loop.

I moved most of that logic inside the the `go_` functions and added an up and down for you as well.

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
TURTLE_SIZE = 200

def go_left():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x > TURTLE_SIZE - 576:
        x -= 3
        t.setx(x)
    screen.update()

def go_right():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        x += 3
        t.setx(x)
    screen.update()

def go_up():  # added this function
    y = t.ycor()
    if y < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        y += 3
        t.sety(y)
    screen.update()

def go_down():  # added this function
    y = t.ycor()
    if y < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        y -= 3
        t.sety(y)
    screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1152,648)
screen.tracer(0)

t = Turtle()
t.shape("circle")
t.speed("slowest")
t.color("blue")
t.penup()
t.setx(338)
t.sety(0)
screen.update()

# Keyboard
screen.onkeypress(go_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(go_down, 'Down')   # added this listener
screen.onkeypress(go_up, 'Up')       # added this listner
screen.onkeypress(go_right, 'Right')
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```